# Function return doesn't wait for angularjs promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a problem about the angularjs promises, maybe someone can point me to right direction. I have a validation function in my controller which should return true if everything is good, returns false, if there is a problem. Single page app works on this assumption, so I can't easily change this assumption...

```
window.customerValidation = function ($scope, $rootScope, $alert, $q) {
        var isValidated = false;


        if (!$scope.scopeData.customer.nationalId && !$scope.scopeData.customer.passportNumber && !$scope.scopeData.customer.driverLicenseNumber) {
            $alert.error("Please enter at least one identification info.");
            return false;
        }


        $scope.scopeData.customer.checkForDuplicateIdentity().then(function () {
            var customer = $scope.scopeData.customer;
            if (!customer.idValidated) {
                $alert.error(customer.idValidationMessage);
            }

            if (!customer.idValidated)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if ($scope.customerDataForm && $scope.customerDataForm.$error && $scope.customerDataForm.$error.required) {
                var missingFields = [];
                angular.forEach($scope.customerDataForm.$error.required, function (value, key) {
                    missingFields.push("-" + value.$name);
                });

                $alert.error("Please fill in the all required fields.\r\n" + missingFields.join("\r\n"));
            }
            else if ($scope.customerDataForm && $scope.customerDataForm.$error && $scope.customerDataForm.$error.email) {
                var invalidEmailFields = [];
                angular.forEach($scope.customerDataForm.$error.email, function (value, key) {
                    invalidEmailFields.push("-" + value.$name);
                });

                $alert.error("Please enter valid e-mail addresses.\r\n" + invalidEmailFields.join("\r\n"));
            }
            else if (!Date.parse($scope.scopeData.customer.dateOfBirth)) {
                $alert.error("Please enter a valid date for Date of Birth.");
            }
            else {
                $scope.scopeData.customer.updateIndividualCustomerInfoRequest();
                $scope.scopeData.customer.updateOrder();
                $rootScope.customerName = $scope.scopeData.customer.firstName + " " + $scope.scopeData.customer.lastName;
                isValidated = true;
            }

        });

        return isValidated;


    };
```

Everything was working fine until requirements changed lately, I am trying to check server to see if id values have been used in the system before. Therefore I have to make an async call to server and check it, you can see that I used 
$scope.scopeData.customer.checkForDuplicateIdentity() method and promises to get the async call work.

Call works fine I tested it, only problem I have is my customerValidation method finishes before async call completes and returns false all the time. Which is to say

return isValidated line always executes before isValidated becomes true.

I can't make the outer return statement wait for the async call's completion. If I return isValidated from inner function, it won't return the value to customerValidation function. Can somebody tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Return promise instead of boolean.

Comment: Do you mean that I should return promise in customerValidation function?

Comment: In what way are you using this function?

Comment: validation method is called, return value is checked if it is true, next controller-view is displayed. If it is false, error message is alerted without any change in display. Execution code is generic and works for 6-7 controllers, so It won't be easy to change it, it expects a boolean value to be returned

Answer (score 0):

A function that calls an async function must be an async function itself. Change `window.customerValidation` so it returns a promise.

- remove `var isValidated = false;`
- replace `return false` by `return $q.reject()` on line 7
- add return in front of `$scope.scopeData.customer.checkForDuplicateIdentity()`
- inside the callback you give to `then`, `return` when the validation passes, and `throw` an error when it fails

Then in the caller of `window.customerValidation` replace

```
if (window.customerValidation()) {
    // validation passed
} else {
    // validation failed
}
```

by

```
window.customerValidation()
    .then(function () {
        // validation passed
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // validation failed
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always use the timeout functions provided by javascript, like

```
setTimeout(function {DO_SOMETHING}, 50);
```

This will wait 50ms before calling the function. This way you can wait for the async call to complete.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought about it too, but that will make things completely undeterministic, what if request takes 1000 ms to process due to heavy load.

Comment: Thats right, but still. I had the same problem and this was the only solution I could come up with... And it works fine (because my calls only take 0-10ms at maximum).

Comment: It is worth to mention that it has the same problem, return isValidated will be executed before DO_SOMETHING is executed.

Comment: This does always depend on the timeout that has been set. In this case I have set 50ms as a timeout. If the async call takes longer to finish than 50ms, isValidated gets returned before. I have tried to find a better answer to your question and found out that you can use a Promise. Read more about it here (its explained really well) [Click here to read more](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)